# How to Make a Static Method Thread Safe in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC project and I want to create a static method that will accept a class and the ModelState as the parameters to use by the Controllers. Do I need to use the locking object to make this static method thread safe?

```
    public class Checker
    {
        private static Object myLock = new Object();
        public static bool CheckMaxStringLengthOf8000Error(IMyClass myclass, ModelStateDictionary ModelState)
        {
            
            lock (myLock)
            {
                string errorMessage = "Cannot exceed 8000 characters";
                bool hasError = false;

                var propsList = myclass.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (var property in propsList)
                {
                    if (property.PropertyType.Name.Contains("String"))
                    {

                        var valueLength = propertyValue?.ToString()?.Length ?? 0;
                        if (valueLength > 8000)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(property.Name, errorMessage);
                            hasError = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (hasError)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot save data. Please reduce the length of your response(s).");
                }
                return hasError;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your thread safety concern here? Also, are you aware that ASP .NET has model validation built-in and you don't need to write your own? i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#validation-attributes

Comment: I'm fully aware of the built-in validation that MS has, but it's a special requirement to by pass the validation to saving partial data without going through the validation before submitting the complete data. The code work but I just want to know if the code will be thread safe as is? Do I need the Locking mechanism to make it thread safe? Any feedback is appreciated.